# PHP convert array list value to field aliase

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to convert array list in to field alias. example:

```
$keymap = ['id' => projectId, 'name' => projName];
```

Then from that array given, i want to do this convert:

```
$keymap = ['id as projectId', 'name as projName'];
```

My goal is I have a json format response from api then I want to change the name of the key of each response based on the $keymap.

Any idea how? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following?

```
foreach($keymap as $key=>$value
{
    $new_array[] = $key.' as '.$value;
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: Thanks, simple enough!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$keymap = ['id' => projectId, 'name' => projName];
$keymap2 = [];
foreach($keymap as $k => $v){
    $keymap2[] = $k.' as '.$v;
}
$keymap = $keymap2;
```

//You should get this
`$keymap = ['id as projectId', 'name as projName'];`

Comment: your script result will print the indexes like [0],[1]. Please take note. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

alternative...

```
  $keymap = ['id' => projectId, 'name' => projName];
    function transform(&$item, $key){   
         $item = $key. ' as '.$item;
    }
    array_walk($keymap, 'transform');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using following way:

```
<?php
$keymap = ['id' => '123', 'name' => '456'];
$newArr = [];
foreach ($keymap as $key => $value) {
   $newArr[]=$key." as ".$value;
}
echo json_encode($newArr);
//output: ["id as 123","name as 456"]

?>
```